# Finding MySQL localhost URL and/or accessing phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, localhost, mysql-workbench

Going around in circles. Please help, I enter h`ttp://localhost` into safari on my mac and receive: It works!

However, I cannot figure out how using MySQL workbench I can find the URL. I am looking to code JSON in xCode to retrieve data from my local MySQL database, however, I do not even know the URL to access it.

My port is on 3306. I have tried `http://127.0.0.1:3306` - and get a failed to open.

Do I need myphpadmin or can I go direct to MySQL?

I have tried saving a copy of MyPhPAdmin under Users>MyUserName> but this did not work when I ran: `http://localhost/myphpadmin`

Should the file be saved elsewhere? When I worked on Python weeks ago I run it under a different location then was recommended (Under the Python X.X cache folder) whereas online people simply ran it from their Users>MyUserName> folder. I am on the latest Catalina OS X.

Tried `http://localhost/usr/local/mysql-8.0.20-macos10.15-x86_64/phpmyadmin/` - 404 not found

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MySQL, you can connect via localhost "socket" or networking "TCP/IP" connections. The user accounts in MySQL exist separately from each other, so if your user account exists with host value 'localhost' the TCP/IP connection probably won't work for you. Also note that, depending on how you installed MySQL and how it's configured, it might not even listen for network connections. Normally, localhost is preferred if you are on the same machine.

In MySQL Workbench, you need to give the hostname or IP address when selecting "Standard (TCP/IP)" from the "Connection Method" dropdown. This is simply the hostname or IP address, not a complete URL or web site. So you'd set the hostname to "127.0.0.1" or "192.168.9.34" or whatever. Again, Local Socket/Pipe is usually a better choice in most cases.

MySQL uses its own networking port (3306) and communication protocol, so using http://127.0.0.1 is incorrect as it isn't using the http protocol. Likewise, if you would need to change the port for some reason, specify that in the port field rather than as a part of the hostname.

As for phpMyAdmin, you would install that to a folder that is handled by your web server, then access it through the URL/path exposed by the web server — by default, your user home directory is not shared to the web (and rightly so, I don't want all of my documents and files shared with the world!). Put the phpMyAdmin folder in your web root and you'll have better success. Which folder that is probably depends a lot on which webserver you are running, how it is installed, and how you configured it.

I won't comment on the Python scripts you've run in the past, as my experience with serving Python to the web requires adjusting some settings in my nginx configuration and I won't want to confuse you compared to the tutorials you're following.